# How to use If CONTAINS to remove variables containing certain words

Tags: sas, contains

I am trying to use SAS to remove certain project names from a dataset. We want to remove any project names that have the words "seminar" or "workshop" from our dataset. The below code is not running, it is giving warnings for each letter of "workshop" and saying it is invalid. If there is a better format to find and delete things in SAS please let me know which function to use.

I tried this code:

```
    data before;
    if find(projectname, "seminar", "workshop" then delete;
    run;
```

Answer (score 0):

FIND() can only search for one term at a time. You can chain it with an OR for just two words.

```
data before;
set have;

if find(projectname, "seminar", "it") or find(projectName, "workshop", "it") then delete;
run;
```